# How to bold particular text in the result from SQL Server procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a column in my stored procedure which contains following data, in row by row manner :

> Ajay Tegar (1052), Amol Kumar Gupta (1409), Dilip Yadav (1369)

Now I want only data in brackets to be bold and else everything regular, like so:

> Ajay Tegar (**1052**), Amol Kumar Gupta (**1409**), Dilip Yadav
>   (**1369**)

I am using grid view to show these data in asp.net web page.

Comment: do it in application

Comment: Please post your html code also

Comment: SQL Server is only concerned about the data - and it returns it properly to you. The **formatting** is up to your front end (web app, reporting) to handle - not SQL Server ....

Comment: In your grid view do the proper formatting (Template column) to display these data in Bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code at code side to bold particular text in gridview -

```
Label lbl_emp_name = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_empName_report");
            if (lbl_emp_name.Text.Contains("("))
            {
                string [] splitedText =  lbl_emp_name.Text.Split('(');
                lbl_emp_name.Text = splitedText[0] + "<b>(" + splitedText[1] + "</b>";
            }
```